# Can't get VirtualHosts to inherit global settings from default-server.conf in Apache 2.4 on SLES 12

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, sles

I am using Apache 2.4.10 on SLES 12. According to the the SLES 12 Administration Guide the default-server.conf file is "Global configuration for all virtual hosts with reasonable defaults. Instead of changing the values, overwrite them with a virtual host configuration." What I am trying to do is add

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

directives to the default-server in order to make sure all vHosts inherit the Rewrite conditions and rules from httpd.conf. However unless the above directives are placed in each and every vHost definition, they do not inherit. How do I apply these settings globally to all vHosts?

Here is my vHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/test
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test-access_log combined
    HostnameLookups Off
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerSignature off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/server.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca.crt
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 5
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire +StdEnvVars

    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir public_html
        Include /etc/apache2/mod_userdir.conf
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/test">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        <IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
            Order allow,deny
            <LimitExcept GET POST>
                Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
            Require method GET POST
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have? I dont see it in the vhost. RewriteEngine On

Comment: Yes it is in httpd.conf. This would work if it were included each of the vhost definitions but I would like for it to be inherited from default-server.conf instead.